# Tomato firmware - View port 80 traffic

Tags: tomato, router

I'm using a WRT54GL router and i've installed the tomato firmware. Is there any shell command or somehting i can use to view all port 80 traffic? I want to se which internal ip has a connection to an external ip. Adress resolving is a plus.

Is this something i can do with tomato?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to upload and install tcpdump for tomato. You'll need to wget the file and host it somehow and then wget it onto your device. Put in /usr/local/bin or some /bin in your $PATH for easy keeping. See link for file: [**link**](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21525639-Tomato-GNULinux-Tips-Tricks)

Once you get it installed run something like this (modify for proper interface)

**tcpdump -i eth0 -n port 80**

See [**tcpdump cheat sheet**](http://packetlife.net/static/cheatsheets/tcpdump.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, works like a charm. But, now i'm only getting all dst hosts, is it possible to get all absolute urls?

Comment: @Alexander Nyquist, trying running the -a option, that should resolve IP addresses to domains. This could be "countered" by having a more than one domain to an IP address, in which cause you would get the reserve DNS hostname. You can check all domains hosted on a single IP address here: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/

Comment: Oh yeah, I just remembered that the -n option doesn't resolve URLs :D. I normally try not to crush my boxes and turning that on only when I need it. So it was instinctive.